# Position of cursor rectangle in QTextEdit (PySide6)

Tags: python, qt, qtextedit, pyside6, qtextcursor

I need to get absolute cursor position (in pixels) in QTextEdit.

I try

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100)

        self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.text_edit.document())
        self.cursor.insertText('abc yz abc')

        self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.text_edit.document())
        self.cursor.setPosition(4)
        self.cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveOperation.Right, QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveMode.KeepAnchor, 2)
        self.text_edit.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
        print(self.text_edit.cursorRect(self.cursor))
        print(self.text_edit.mapToGlobal(self.text_edit.cursorRect(self.cursor).topLeft()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    main = MyWidget(dialog)
    dialog.setGeometry(10,10,200,200)
    dialog.show()
    app.exec()
```

I wait that `cursorRect(self.cursor)` return rectangle that select `yz` chars, but it don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two basic problems with your code.  Firstly, from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextedit.html#cursorRect) (my emphasis)...

> returns a rectangle (**in viewport coordinates**) that includes the
> cursor.

So the `print` statement should be...

```
print(self.text_edit.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.text_edit.cursorRect(self.cursor).topLeft()))
```

Secondly, you're printing the cursor coordinates from the `__init__` method so the widget isn't visible and the real geometry isn't known.  Add a simple `paintEvent` implementation that shows the coords and schedules a further update...

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    super(MyWidget, self).paintEvent(event)
    print(self.text_edit.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.text_edit.cursorRect(self.cursor).topLeft()))
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, self.update)
```

The code shown above is for demonstration purposes only and shouldn't be considered for 'real' applications.  It should, however, output the correct cursor coordinates.

A better example that make use of a simple 10Hz `QTimer` would be...

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_edit.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 100)

        self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.text_edit.document())
        self.cursor.insertText('abc yz abc')

        self.cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(self.text_edit.document())
        self.cursor.setPosition(4)
        self.cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveOperation.Right, QtGui.QTextCursor.MoveMode.KeepAnchor, 2)
        self.text_edit.setTextCursor(self.cursor)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.show_cursor_position)
        self.timer.start(100)

    def show_cursor_position(self):
        print(self.text_edit.viewport().mapToGlobal(self.text_edit.cursorRect(self.cursor).topLeft()))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    main = MyWidget(dialog)
    dialog.setGeometry(10,10,200,200)
    dialog.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against calling `self.update()` in the `paintEvent()` with a timer, and especially with an untraceable single shot static call: the widget might receive multiple paint events, which will accumulate self.update requests. Interestingly enough, in this case it's practically useless (calling `self.update()` on a scroll area has no effect), but suggesting this might be dangerous for beginners that would think that it's an acceptable practice. A standard widget already receives multiple paint events on its own, but this is much more important for complex ones like this case.

Comment: In the case of QTextEdit (which also is a scroll area) this means that it will receive paint events when: it's shown, it's resized, the scroll bars are moved, the cursor blinks, the cursor is moved and the text is edited. This will result in *hundreds* of almost recursive scheduled update requests and resulting paint events: if you change that timer callback to the *actual* call for a scroll area (`self.viewport().update`), you'll see the result.

Comment: @musicamante I agree with what you're saying but The `self.update` call was really just for demonstration purposes -- to show that the values printed from `__init__` were not really 'representative'.  I certainly wouldn't recommend doing that in real code.

Comment: I understand what was the purpose, but the point remains: `self.update()` on a scroll area is practically a no-op for `paintEvent()` overrides: QAbstractScrollArea doesn't paint anything of its own, except for the corner panel (if shown) and the frame, but that only happens at the `event()` level, it's never passed to the `paintEvent()` function (as it does for "normal" widgets), which instead is only called for `Paint` events received by the viewport. Try to increase the interval to a couple of seconds and make the text edit read only (to avoid blinking): `paintEvent()` will *not* be called.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again :-) I've seen your new example, and it's certainly more appropriate, but it has an issue: you're using `self.cursor`, which is a "static" QTextCursor, as argument of `cursorRect()`; in this way, the result can be quite unexpected: for instance, moving the cursor with the keyboard or mouse doesn't change the output, and editing the text will move *that* referenced text cursor position, which won't be relative to the *visible* cursor position (the "caret"). That function should always use the `self.textCursor()` dynamic function if it has to show the *current* cursor.